# Angular - Use service array to automatically create components/pages

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to create a kind of automation for my web app.

I have a service with an array. I want every entry to have its own page - so far therefore I've created a template which I used in single components for each case (hence I had 8 components) - I filled the template for each component by iterating to the allocated entries (I only had to change the index for each case component). These components were reachable by routing.

*In a nutshell, I had to create a component for each case manually, but the content was kind of automated.*

**Is there a way to let Angular automatically create pages/components for each case, f.e. by also iterating through the array?**

To be exact, I want solely have to add another entry to the service array for Angular to create a single page for the case? Is there a way to realize this behavior?

Service:

```
export const CASES: Case[] = [
  { name: 'Diesel',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/diesel.png',
    image: '/assets/images/diesel.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-sunflower.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-cap.png', link: '/cases/diesel' },

  { name: 'WeWork Berlin',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/berlin.png',
    image: '/assets/images/berlin.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/wework/berlin-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/wework/berlin-building.png',
    link: '/cases/wework' },

  { name: 'Fritzhansen',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/fritzhansen.png',
    image: '/assets/images/fritzhansen.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/fritzhansen/women.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/fritzhansen/chairs.jpeg',
    link: '/cases/fritzhansen' },

  { name: 'Savum',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/savum.png',
    image: '/assets/images/savum/savum-front.png',
    image2: '/assets/images/savum/savum-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/savum/savum-iphone.png',
    link: '/cases/savum' },

  { name: 'Eskay',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/eskay.png',
    image: '/assets/images/eskay.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/eskay/front.jpg',
    image3: '/assets/images/eskay/inner.jpg',
    link: '/cases/eskay' },

  { name: 'Diesel Fashion',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/diesel-snd.png',
    image: '/assets/images/diesel-snd.png',
    image2: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-sunflower.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-cap.png',
    link: '/cases/diesel' },

  { name: 'Mobilia',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/mobilia.png',
    image: '/assets/images/mobilia.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/mobilia/green.jpg',
    image3: '/assets/images/mobilia/pink.jpg',
    link: '/cases/mobilia' },

  { name: 'Rarekind',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/rarekind.png',
    image: '/assets/images/rarekind.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/rarekind/tube.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/rarekind/red.png',
    link: '/cases/rarekind' }
];
```

Comment: The command, `ng g c *component_name*` automatically create a component. Consider doing a loop on that cases, and doing a`ng g c case.name`

Comment: Do your 8 components basically look the same? Then you don't need multiple components but just one component that is reachable under multiple routes with different input data. The Angular Tutorial covers this scenario in the section about routing: [Navigate to Hero Details](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#navigating-to-hero-details)

Comment: @fridoo Yes thanks, this one did the trick. But there's one issue - I have a link inside of the component which leads to the next case - clicking this case will change the link, but it's content won't be reloaded, hence the content won't update to the next case.

Comment: When you navigate to the same component `ngOnInit` won't be executed again so you have to work with Observables. Use `this.route.paramMap.pipe(..).subscribe(..)` in `ngOnInit` to listen and react to parameter changes in the url. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8qg6p

Comment: @fridoo Thanks works, but I also have some other function which are being executed in ngOnInit - where do I put those?

Comment: You could use the rxjs operator `tap` for side effects.

Comment: @fridoo How do I realize that in code - have never user rxjs before.

Comment: If you've never used rxjs you should really start with a tutorial as Angular apps heavily rely on rxjs. The Angular Tutorial also has a section about it [RxJS Library](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library). To execute some code whenever an Observable emits you could do `observable.pipe(tap(value => someCode(value))).subscribe()` or `observable.subscribe(value => someCode(value))`.